# Adding large node modules to an Azure function

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I am experimenting with Azure functions using Node. Firstly, it seems you need to add the azure package to your module which seems a bit odd when deploying to a function to Azure. However, my main question is, what is exactly the recommended approach when deploying large npm packages to Azure?

1. I  tried via the command line kudos but that works incredibly
   slow. Typing `npm install azure` never finished. It took forever.
2. I off course don't want to checkin the module in my github account.
   It is massive.
3. There is the push and zip approach. Are we then to
   zip the enitre function together with the module? The azure module
   is a few hundred mb. No small thing for a function which just wants
   to access a few service bus queues or write to cosmos.

How do you normally deploy Node functions to azure with large npm packages?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions do not require to install any Node.js packages including `azure`, unless you actually need them for your function body.

If you do need modules, to reduce deployment size and cold start time it makes sense to bundle the modules together. Have a look at [funcpack](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-pack) - Webpack based command-line tool for doing so. Basically, you run it locally, and then deploy the packed files to Azure, e.g. with Run-as-Zip approach or otherwise.

Comment: In this case I need the **azure** package for my function.I need to access azure specific components. Which brings me to my original question, how do you deploy it with such large packages? If it zip the function, then I assume it would include the module which would be quit large indeed.